# HTTP post body gets split by server

Tags: node.js, express

I send a source of an image to a server, where I want to download the image. When I send the src of the image, the server console logs it with weird artefacts. The server splits the url at the symbols `=` and at others symbols. How can I transfer the URL of the image as plain text to the server?

Image src:

```
http://sammlungonline.kunstmuseumbasel.ch/eMuseumPlus?service=DynamicAsset&sp=SU5mxm4Yx%2FVbg9LVP7MZLDqo6z5lhONBxez%2FYx5EhVSCZjU0bcvvsnPxkoLiFJnF9QzRY98OZwV3L%0ATpwyJeR7NMPvp3RRP61q%2FZaOrpMIarVgjD3DclO99bux9fyJN9j3&sp=Simage%2Fjpeg
```

Console Log Server after Post:

```
  'http://sammlungonline.kunstmuseumbasel.ch/eMuseumPlus?service': 'DynamicAsset',
  sp: [
    'SU5mxm4Yx/Vbg9LVP7MZLDqo6z5lhONBxez/Yx5EhVSCZjU0bcvvsnPxkoLiFJnF9QzRY98OZwV3L\n' +
      'TpwyJeR7NMPvp3RRP61q/ZaOrpMIarVgjD3DclO99bux9fyJN9j3',
    'Simage/jpeg'
  ]
}
```

Client

```
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
Http.open("POST", API_URL);
Http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
Http.send(image);
```

Server

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const url = require('url')
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
const port = 8000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  

app.post('/bilder', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send("hello world")
});
```

Comment: You can try `Http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');`

Comment: How do I parse it then to get the body of the req? If I use `'Content-Type', 'text/plain'` I get an empty string

Comment: you need to use `body-parser` for that. Use `app.use(bodyParser.text())`

Comment: alright! it worked